# Return control to shell DURING `gvim -f`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gvim

I occasionally use `gvim -f` to start gvim but force the shell to wait for the gvim session to end before resuming execution of whatever it's doing (for instance, I usually edit my bash aliases using an alias that calls `gvim -f` then reloads my `.bashrc` file after I quit gvim).

Sometimes, however, I realize that I'd like to continue editing the file, but I also want to resume work in the shell. For instance, in the example use above, sometimes I'd like to test whether an alias I've just written will actually do what I want, and if not, I'd like to fix it to behave correctly. (Yes, I realize that there are several other ways of ccomplishing this; it's just an example.)

Is it possible to return control to the shell from a `gvim -f` command WITHOUT closing the gvim session?

(For instance, is there a way to make gvim send some sort of spurious "I'm done" signal back to the shell, but retain control? Or is there a way to turn the current process into a background process without killing it?)

(I'm adding the `bash` tag because that's the shell I'm currently using, but ideally I'd like a shell-agnostic solution.)

EDIT: original post mentioned "disowning the child process," which, I now realize, is actually not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Use `ctrl-z` to suspend the gvim process and then `bg` to put it in the brackgroung from the shell?

Comment: That is precisely what I needed. Thank you. If you write that up as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do this from within gvim but normal shell job control operations can do this.

Use <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> to suspend the foreground gvim process and then use `bg` to resume the process in the background and allow the shell to continue normal operation. (This is essentially all gvim is doing without `-f` anyway though in a slightly different manner.)